# How to make a dictionary comprehension with inline if?

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to combine a dictionary comprehension and an inline `if` statement.
The comprehension loops over all items and as long as the item has not the key `id`
it creates a new key: `job[old_key]`.

**Code**

```
job = {'id':1234, 'age':17, 'name':'dev'}
args = {'job[%s]' % k:v if k != 'id' else k:v for k, v in job}
```

**Wished output**

```
print args
{'id':1234, 'job[age]':17, 'job[name]':'dev'}
```

A `SyntaxError` was raised.

```
args = {'job[%s]' % k:v if k != 'key' else k:v for k, v in job}
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However, when I try to run my script Python complains about `k:v`.
How can I combine a dictionary comprehension and an inline if statement?

**Note**: I know that I can easily achieve that task with a `for` loop, but I just want 
to combine these two elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key and value parts are *separate* expressions. Use the conditional expression in just the key part:

```
args = {'job[%s]' % k if k != 'id' else k: v for k, v in job.iteritems()}
```

The `:` is not part of either expression, only of the dictionary comprehension syntax. You also need to loop over both keys and values; in Python 2, use `job.iteritems()`, Python 3, `job.items()`.

Demo:

```
>>> job = {'id':1234, 'age':17, 'name':'dev'}
>>> {'job[%s]' % k if k != 'id' else k: v for k, v in job.iteritems()}
{'id': 1234, 'job[age]': 17, 'job[name]': 'dev'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21728565/how-to-make-a-dictionary-comprehension-with-inline-if#21728599), you can make it more readable as follows

```
get_key = lambda k: ('job[%s]' if k != 'id' else '%s') % k
args = { get_key(key): val for key, val in job.iteritems()}
```